# Can we use pixels instead of techniques like word2vec?

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, pixel, deep-learning, word2vec

I have a question about NLP. In NLP we use word2vec which converts words into vectors which then are fed to the neural network to output sentiment classification, for example. I think we can input pixels of words, which will be vectors, same process as we do with images, which then will be fed into neural network to output sentiment classification.

Do you guys think it will work? I think it should.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you are trying to detect which letters are written. As you told it is about NLP, I assume you already know which word is there. What I think is you want to make sense out of those words. This is what we do in NLP. So why not directly use the meaning itself rather than going to pixel level.

What I think is as long as you want to make sense out of words, it's better to directly use word2vector form rather than going to pixel form.